# in Google Analytics can settings, like filters, funnels etc. be defined afterwards and still efect prior data?

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

From a 'gradually adding more reports'- standpoint:

is it possible to add settings like filters, ecommerce-metrics, funnels, etc. 1 at a time, and still have them be applied to the data prior to the date you applied the settings? (have the settings backward propagated if that's correct english)

I can image if GA keeps the raw underlying data this is technically possible.

This would be useful IMO, since it means I wouldn't have to invest a lot of time upfront to learn to build the best possible funnels, etc. but I could learn it gradually instead without being worried of missing out valueable data being created that I can't base my reports on in the mean-time.

Thanks, 
Geert-Jan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, no.

You might want to look into Segments, with apply to all data. But they don't have the same effects than filters and goals.

Comment: To elaborate, Google Analytics specifically does not keep personalized data relating to analytics. This includes individual IP addresses and other identifying data. As such, filters (generally based on identifying data) will be unable to affect already-collected data.

Comment: Also, a good policy is to keep a profile intact, and experiment with a copy. That way you can always access the raw data.

Comment: how does that work "keep a profile intact", something like having to GA-accounts log the same raw data?

Comment: to GA-accounts --> two GA-accounts

Comment: never mind. found it: http://code.google.com/intl/nl-NL/apis/analytics/docs/concepts/gaConceptsAccounts.html#profiles